# Why does Agent Smith call the Oracle mom?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-matrix-revolutions

In Matrix Revolutions, when Smith and Oracle meet, she calls him a bastard and he says "you would know, mom". What does this imply? Why does he call her mom?

Comment: The oracle is one of the most ancient programs and acts as a counterpart to the architect. So I'd guess she had some part in creating the agents. Oracle=Mom, Architect=Dad

Comment: I thought the Oracle was a counter-intuitive program focused on ensuring majority accept the matrix program. She's not there to ensure gate keeping and security.

Comment: The Architect himself says in *Matrix Reloaded* about the Oracle: "An intuitive program initially created to investigate certain aspects of the human psyche. **If I am the father of the Matrix, she would undoubtedly be its mother.**"

Comment: .. and that takes it to the other question I had - http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41129/what-does-the-architects-condescending-please-imply

Comment: @Walt: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Or he is just replying to her with an insult and by calling her mom implies, that he is her bastard, that she was a bad person who had a baby outside of marriage.