# What does the Architect's condescending "please" imply?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-matrix-reloaded

In the movie Matrix Reloaded, when Neo meets the Architect, one of the statements the Architect makes is - "If I am the father of the matrix, she would undoubtedly be its mother."

For which Neo says "The Oracle". The Architect responds with a very condescending "Please" and continues.

What is he imply with this "Please"? That the mother is not the Oracle? If not the Oracle then who is it?

Comment: *"The Architect responds with a very condescending "Please" and continues."* I thought it meant he just thought of her by a different, (less flattering) title..

Comment: I took it to be just a condescending form of 'duh', really.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that. Possible that the name Oracle is given by the humans. However, even the Merovingian calls her the Fortune Teller. I wonder is there is anyone else who can be placed in the position of Mother.

Comment: *"However, even the Merovingian calls her the Fortune Teller."*  The term 'oracle' has a lot more respect implied in it, than 'fortune teller' - even though they **mean** essentially the same thing.  Tip: Add @Walt (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's simple. He's dismissive of her supposed ability to see the future. Neither the Oracle or the Architect can see past human choice, just making probable chance/possibility statistics/computated results/educated guesses about how humans will react or of they succeed. Neo being the proof that they can't (he chooses to save Trinity and succeeds against all reasonable belief).

The please is about her title, not her status of matrix Co creator. Notice that a few sentences earlier he says that it took someone "not as smart" or "not as perfect" as himself to figure it out, a psychology program (i.e. the Oracle).

The Architect is pretty condescending and dismissive the entire conversation in the first place.

Comment: I strongly disagree that The Oracle was the co-creator, but there is no proof either way in Reloaded. "Please" was his way of saying "you're wrong and I'm brushing this topic aside" without saying the co-creator was Persephone: a program created to explore human emotions, not choice.

Comment: @snowman yet smith goes after the Oracle, and gets super powers, and at the end it's mom and pop talking about the humans.